# How to resolve `SSL SYSCALL Error` with a PostgreSQL Database on Azure?

Tags: psql, azure-postgresql

After restarting my PostgreSQL on Azure Database Instance, I can no longer connect via any client and I receive: `psql: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected` with psql.

I used the `Restart` button on the *Azure Database for PostgreSQL server* overview page.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely server was in the process of rebooting. Check in the server logs server start time. Probably it will be after you issues your connection request. If you have heavy workload running then recovery is expected to take longer.